# Sorry, check with the site admin for error: EISDIR .. (CRA)

Tags: reactjs

I've deployed on same ubuntu server two small react apps. I've divided by relative path, like `/app1` and `/app2`, but I have problem when refreshing the page or after appending slash at the end of the url, like `https://example.com/app1/` or `https://example.com/app2/`.

The error is: Sorry, check with the site admin for error: EISDIR.

How I can eliminate this type of error. I can't find anything related with this error with React.

I've tried both, with setting `PUBLIC_URL` in `.env.production` to `/app1/` or `"homepage": "/app1"` in `package.json`.

BR,

Comment: Did you eventually solved this? I'm experiencing the same thing in a react app

Comment: Facing the exact same issue on a `React` site, pre-rendered with `react-snap` and the build folder being served by `PM2` behind `nginx` proxy on a ubuntu server on a digital ocean droplet.